# Getting Specflow Tag in WebDriver Method

Tags: c#, automated-tests, specflow, xunit

I am running an automated test suite using c#, selenium, and specflow.  If possible, I would like to be able to see what tag(s) are assigned to the current scenarios so I can instantiate a certain browser type per scenario. Is this even possible using XUnit??

Login Feature File:

```
Feature: Login
    In order to login to DRIVE
    As a user
    We have to enter login details

Background:
    Given I am on the login page

@headless
Scenario: Logging in as a valid user
    And I enter a valid user and password
    When I submit the login form
    Then The user should be logged in
```

WebDriverContext.cs file

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.PhantomJS;

namespace Drive.Acceptance.Tests
{
    public interface IWebDriverContext {
        IWebDriver GetDriver();
    }

    public class WebDriverContext : IWebDriverContext
    {
        private static volatile WebDriverContext _instance;
        private static readonly object Lock = new object();

        public static IWebDriverContext Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                {
                    lock (Lock)
                    {
                        if (_instance == null)
                            _instance = new WebDriverContext();
                    }
                }

                return _instance;
            }

        }

        public IWebDriver GetDriver()
        {
            lock (Lock)
            {
                // TODO: create headless browser if scenario is tagged with @headless
                if (!TagName.Contains("headless")) {
                    return new ChromeDriver();
                }
                else {
                    return new PhantomJSDriver();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get a list of tags of the Scenario in the ScenarioContext.

```
ScenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Tags
```

see https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/blob/master/TechTalk.SpecFlow/ScenarioInfo.cs

You can get the actual ScenarioContext via Context-Injection (http://specflow.org/documentation/Context-Injection/) or via ScenarioContext.Current (http://specflow.org/documentation/ScenarioContext/).
If possible get it via Context- Injection. That way, you will not have future problems if you want to run the tests in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Adding one more point, If you want to get tags at feature level you can use

FeatureContext.Current.FeatureInfo.Tags