# Is it possible to add tags or have multiple BeforeTestRun hooks in Specflow

Tags: selenium, specflow

So I currently have an automation pack that I have created using Selenium/Specflow.

I wanted to know whether it is possible to have multiple `BeforeTestRun` hooks?

I've already tried: `[BeforeTestRun("example1")]` but I receive an error stating *BeforeTestRunAttribute does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments*

I tried the following but that also failed:

```
[BeforeTestRun]
[Scope(Tag = "example1")]
```

And referenced the above in the .feature file like this:

```
@example1
Scenario: This is an example
    Given...
    When...
    Then...
```

Is there a way to implement this correctly such that in one .feature file I can have two scenarios that can use different `[BeforeTestRun]`?

Comment: Try using `[BeforeScenario] [Scope(Tag = "example1"]` not the `BeforeTestRun` as you want different hook before each scenario level.

Comment: I've tried `[BeforeScenario]` but that will not work for my implementation

Comment: Can you please share what you tried and the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use `[BeforeScenario]` like suggested, you can try to manually check for tags using `if` statements. To get the current tags and compare them to the ones you need, try this:

```
var tags = ScenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Tags;
if (tags.Any(x => x.Equals("MyTag")))
{
    DoWork();
}
```

More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42417623/9742876